# »versichern vor« oder »versichern gegen«

Tags: word-usage, preposition

I have seen those two forms and I can’t decide which use is correct.

> Unser neue Wagen ist [vor/gegen] Diebstahl versichert

Which of the prepositions below suits the sentence best?

Comment: For your information: *versichern vor* does not really exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to express.

If you have a theft insurance (legal protection) and want to mention that, you can say:

> Unser neuer Wagen ist gegen Diebstahl versichert.

However, if you want to talk about security equipment (physical protection, like a special alarm system), you can say:

> Unser neuer Wagen ist vor/gegen Diebstahl geschützt.